# Raspberry + OpenCV: picamera.exc.PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 640x480

Tags: python

I wan't to detect rectangles with the camera of my raspberry.

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3

Raspian Buster (2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full_mit_Settings_und_Updates.img)

OpenCV:   4.2.0  (installed with this instructions, not in a virtual environment, but directly: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/)

```
import time
import cv2
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface_extended.xml')
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
camera.rotation = 180
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size = (640, 480))
time.sleep(0.1)
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rects = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=20, minSize=(75, 75))
    for (i, (x, y, w, h)) in enumerate(rects):
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(image, "Object {}".format(i + 1), (x, y - 10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.55, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Object Detector", image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

Although I have tested everything I found in the www to solve the problem I get the following error(s):

```
Python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
>>> %Run kk3neu_stackoverflow.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/kk3neu_stackoverflow.py", line 19, in <module>
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1702, in capture_continuous
    if not encoder.wait(self.CAPTURE_TIMEOUT):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 395, in wait
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 419, in stop
    self._close_output()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 349, in _close_output
    mo.close_stream(output, opened)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 371, in close_stream
    stream.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 238, in flush
    self.array = bytes_to_rgb(self.getvalue(), self.size or self.camera.resolution)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 127, in bytes_to_rgb
    'Incorrect buffer length for resolution %dx%d' % (width, height))
picamera.exc.PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 640x480
>>>
```

I would be very appreciated if anybody can help me.
Thank you a lot!!

Comment: you need to clear down the stream between captures. The PiRGBArray docs cover doing this with truncate function see http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.7/array.html#picamera.array.PiRGBArray

Comment: Thanks!
Meanwhile I have find the solution.
1) I made indention-bugs in the last 3 lines.

Comment: I removed from the last 3 lines one indention per line.
Then the buffer-error didn*t appear anymore.

2) But the detection of rects didn't work.
    The problem was "minNeighbors=20".
    I changed it to "minNeighbors=1", since then rects are recognized.

So my problem is solved.
Thank you very much.